# Login filter getting redirected in url but view page shows 'This webpage has a redirect loop'

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, xhtml, servlet-filters

The problem starts here i get exception when eclipse reloads context

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.richfaces.application.ServiceTracker.release(ServiceTracker.java:100)
    at org.richfaces.application.InitializationListener.onStop(InitializationListener.java:144)
    at org.richfaces.application.InitializationListener.processEvent(InitializationListener.java:154)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2168)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2144)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4980)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5626)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3947)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

my web.xml is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>JsfEaxmples</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>1</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.SEPARATOR_CHAR</param-name>
    <param-value>-</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
    <param-value>classic</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.RECREATE_VALUE_EXPRESSION_ON_BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>

  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>

    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <filter>
  <filter-name>sessionfilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.invoice.sessionfilter</filter-class>

  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>sessionfilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/Jsf Invoice System/*</url-pattern>

  </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

i couldn't understand where the problem is whelther the problem is in my web.xml or in filter. my filter is here

```
package com.invoice;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Servlet Filter implementation class sessionfilter
 */


public class sessionfilter implements Filter {
    String uname;

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public sessionfilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#destroy()
     */
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain)
     */
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // place your code here

        // pass the request along the filter chain
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        login b=(login)req.getSession().getAttribute("login");
        String url= req.getContextPath() +"/Login.xhtml";
        if(req.getRequestURI().equals(url))
        {
        if(b!=null && b.isLoggedIn())
        {
            res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath()+"/Jsf Invoice System/invoiceinfo.xhtml");  

        }
        else
        {

               // res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath()+"/Jsf Invoice System/Login.xhtml");
            chain.doFilter(request, response);  
        }
        }
        else
        {

            if(b!=null && b.isLoggedIn())
            {
                 chain.doFilter(request, response); 

            }
            else
            {

                 res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath()+"/Jsf Invoice System/Login.xhtml");


            }   


        }

    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#init(FilterConfig)
     */
    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

should i change my url pattern totally i dont have idea how to proceed

my login bean class is

```
package com.invoice;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@SessionScoped
public class login {

    String username,userpassword,errormess,navipg;

    boolean isLoggedIn;

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return isLoggedIn;
    }

    public void setLoggedIn(boolean isLoggedIn) {
        this.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn;
    }

    public String getNavipg() {
        return navipg;
    }

    public void setNavipg(String navipg) {
        this.navipg = navipg;
    }

    public String getErrormess() {
        return errormess;
    }

    public void setErrormess(String errormess) {
        this.errormess = errormess;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getUserpassword() {
        return userpassword;
    }

    public void setUserpassword(String userpassword) {
        this.userpassword = userpassword;
    }
    public String navigate()
    {
        try
        {

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","invoice","google");
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement(); 
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select username,password from usertable where username='"+username+"' and password='"+userpassword+"' ");
            if(rs.next())
            {

                setErrormess("");
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("uname",this.username );
                navipg="invoiceinfo";
                setLoggedIn(true);


            }
            else

            {

                setErrormess("Invalid Login credentials");
                username="";
                navipg="Login";
                setLoggedIn(false);

            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return navipg;

    }
    public String logout()
    {

         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
         setLoggedIn(false);
            return "Login";

    }




}
```

but i debugged and checked it actually the execution does not enter here

```
String url="/Login.xhtml";
    if(req.getRequestURI().equals(url))
```

line no 50 in filter does not get executed i even changed like this

```
String url="/Jsf Invoice System/Login.xhtml";
        if(req.getRequestURI().equals(url))
```

Please help me and give a solution for this problem

Answer (score -1):

Have a look on this link:
[Filter for User Session Check in JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997792/filter-for-user-session-check-in-jsf-2-0/22755614#22755614)